# Writing up past maths exam papers for collaboration

Tags: online, collaboration

I am working through the past exam papers available for my course. I am then making them available for collaboration using Google Docs.

However, for maths heavy material, the Google Docs equation editor sucks. In fact the MathJaX support on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) here on Stack Exchange is much better.

I am looking for an on-line editor for equation heavy documents that supports collaboration and sharing, and supports LaTeX.

Notes: I am currently reviewing the solutions suggested here;
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Collaborative_Writing_of_LaTeX_Documents

Google Docs is actually quite good. If they just supported a keyboard short-cut for inserting an equation, and had some sensible text in equation selection behaviour.

I tried `latexlab.org`, but it's not a WYSIWYG editor; just an online IDE for LaTeX really (unless I missed something).

`zoho` documents is another service I might look at.

Comment: Also, it is unclear whether you are the teacher or a student. The [homework] tag is a sort of meta-tag to allow people reading to know that the content came from a homework assignment. Perhaps [education] (or a related tag) would fit better.

Comment: maybe a revision tag should be created then.

Comment: Does this post help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/simultaneous-collaborative-editing-of-a-latex-file

Comment: Another related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24736/86

Comment: Probably you would like write equations by hand (mouse)? You could use [TexTablet](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sl203/?id=39), which builds on [Microsoft's Math Input Panel](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows7/Use-Math-Input-Panel-to-write-and-correct-math-equations)

Answer (score 3):

- [ScribTeX](http://scribtex.com/) is capable of online editing, compiling and git integration.
- [MonkeyTeX](http://monkeytex.bradcater.webfactional.com/) is capable of editing, pdf compiling and previewing.